# PyCharm removes unused imports when moving a file

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm for moving files inside my project and PyCharm updates the imports in the project to the new path which is great.

The problem is that it also *removes unused imports* from those files. This is a very bad behavior for me and I can't find a way to stop this.

I can't check whether it did that every time because sometimes its hundreds of files.

Comment: Why would you not want to remove unused imports? Unused imports are useless and can cause issues, I don't see why you would want to keep them.

Comment: There are lots of reasons. For example, when I import a file the code there is being executed but PyCharm still thinks it's unused. And there are more reasons.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a good starting point: [Ignoring "Unused import statement" in just one file (PyCharm)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58975633/14499516)?

Comment: In one file it's possible. I couldn't file an option for all

Comment: Is it PyCharm using "refactoring tool" when moving/renaming files? So you should be able to set and check proposed changes. (and put it in git, so you can still revert or see all changes), so a person needs to approve changes.

Comment: If you’re only importing other files to execute the code contained in them, but you’re not actually using any name they create—in other words, you’re only importing them for their side effects—that’s arguably terrible code structure.

Comment: "For example, when I import a file the code there is being executed but PyCharm still thinks it's unused." relying on imports to execute top level code for side-effects is a *terrible practice*

Comment: I agree. But it is not my code and currently, I'm not going to rewrite it. So please, answer to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible.
This is a known issue: [PY-54707](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54707/Move-refactoring-shouldnt-remove-unused-imports).
Also discussed in this thread: [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000035164-Unconfigurable-Auto-Remove-of-Unused-Python-Imports).

You can use this to protect the a spesific import from removal:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
```

Answer (score 0):

An unused import should be perfectly safe to remove because it *should* not have any effect.

> when I import a file the code there is being executed but PyCharm still thinks it's unused

If an unused import does make a difference to your program, then your code is badly structured.

In Python, it's not possible for imports to define any implicit global variables or other symbols. As a contrast, let's take some PHP code:

```php
<?php

require_once 'foo.php';

$foo = new Foo;
```

If the file `foo.php` defines `Foo`, then it'll be implicitly available when importing that file.

This is *not* how Python works. Python makes available exactly and solely the names you explicitly `import`. So when you write:

```
import foo
```

…and then never refer to `foo`, then the import isn't used, and there's no way it could be implicitly used in some way.

So the only way this could possibly do anything is by executing the top level code in the `foo` module. But since that code cannot have any global effect (like defining "global" classes or other things), the only possible effect it *could* have is some external side effect, like writing to files or other external systems.

(Let's leave aside the possibility of leaning *really* far out the window and modifying some Python internal values like `sys.path`; there's a dedicated circle of hell for this kind of code.)

So I'm reading between the lines that you have all your code written as plain top level code across several files, and it all does some sort of file manipulation, and you're importing them to "orchestrate" several file modifications in a row. E.g. something like:

*`a.py`*

```
with open(..., 'w') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

*`b.py`*

```
with open(..., 'w') as f:
    for i in range(...):
        f.write(...)
```

*`main.py`*

```
import a
import b
# end of file
```

This is not how you're supposed to use modules. For starters, the `import` system is optimised with the assumption that modules only *define* names. The code being executed to achieve this is merely par for the course. If you `import` the same module more than once, the code will only be executed once, the first time the module is imported. Because any name the module defines should already be known then, and there's no need to do it again. `import` does *not* mean "run the code", it means "make the names in this module available in my module".

And because that's how modules are supposed to work, it'll be pretty surprising for anyone else working with your code that a simple `import foo` is creating or modifying any external resources.

How you're *supposed* to write code like this is as such:

1. Wrap any side effect code in a function, which can explicitly be executed if and when needed:

   *`a.py`*

   ```
   def create_data():
       with open(..., 'w') as f:
           ...
   ```
2. If you want to be able to execute this file directly as a standalone script, add this section at the bottom:

   *`a.py`*

   ```
   ...

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       create_data()
   ```

   Now if you run this file directly from the command line like `$ python a.py`, it'll execute `create_data` and write your file as it used to. However, if you `import` it from another file, it won't.
3. When you want to orchestrate the code from another file, `import` the functions you need and call them explicitly:

   *`main.py`*

   ```
   from a import create_data

   create_data()
   ```

With this you can even put multiple functions into the same file, and don't need a separate file for each task. This quickly leads to better code reuse and thus shorter code as well. And with this you're on the right track to be creating proper complex programs. And PyCharm removing unused imports has become a moot point.